# How to get input with preceded characters?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to use `scanf()` for this specific type of input.
The input is as following

```
n = 2
m = 3
```

I understand that `scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);` will not do the work due to the presence of "n=" and "m=", should I not use `scanf()`? or can it be done using some kind of regex or anything?

Comment: What you're trying to do cannot be done without a tremendous amount of work. It's far from trivial.

Comment: If you could get the hands on an implementation of a hash table you could use `scanf("%s = %d\n", &name, &value)` to read line by line the name-value-pairs into this hash table.

Comment: @klutt Can't we do it using `scanf("n = %d\nm = %d");`, then input like `n = 3<kbd>Enter</kbd>m = 4`.

Comment: Are you sure you need that kind of input?  Maybe you could ask the user for n and then he just inputs a number, and the same with m

Comment: @Lucas Yes, you could theoretically do that, but nah.

Comment: Why do you want "n=" to be a part of the input?

Comment: @klutt Yeah, I did test this `scanf("n = %d\nm = %d");` on gcc, clang even on borland and it works on all of 'em.

Answer (score 2):

If the form of your input is:

```
<name><zero or more spaces>=<zero or more spcaes><number>
<name><zero or more spaces>=<zero or more spcaes><number>
```

you can read the `<name>` part without storing it by using `%*` and use `[^=]` to keep reading until a `'='` is found.

It could look like:

```
int main(void) {
    int n,m;
    if (scanf("%*[^=] = %d %*[^=] = %d", &n, &m) != 2) 
    {
        printf("bad input\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Now n is %d and m is %d\n", n, m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will handle input like:

```
n = 2
m = 3
```

and

```
nnnnnn                   =20
mmmmmmm =           100
```

and

```
n = 2
m=3
```

and even single line input like:

```
n      =              2037  m=3733
```

Comment: And also arbitrary line breaks between components of the input, including blank lines.  If you're worried about lines, `scanf()` is the wrong tool for the job, because it doesn't care about lines.

Answer (score 1):

One way, is to catch them as strings first (better use `fgets()` for this than `scanf()`):

```
char buf_a[30];
char buf_b[30];

fgets(buf_a, sizeof(buf_a), stdin);
fgets(buf_b, sizeof(buf_b), stdin);
```

and then parse the input strings:

```
sscanf(buf_a, "n = %d", &n);
sscanf(buf_b, "m = %d", &m);
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char buf_a[30];
    char buf_b[30];

    int n = 0, m = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        if ( !fgets(buf_a, sizeof(buf_a), stdin) ||
             !fgets(buf_b, sizeof(buf_b), stdin) )
        {
            // error routine.
        }

        if ( sscanf(buf_a, "n = %d", &n) &&
             sscanf(buf_b, "m = %d", &m) )
            break;

        printf("Invalid input! Please repeat your input.\n");
    }

    printf("%d\n", n);
    printf("%d", m);
}
```

Execution:

```
./a.out
n = 5
m = 4
5
4
```

Comment: Just another question, what makes using `scanf("n = %d\nm = %d");` bad in this case?

Comment: @Lucas The problem is when the input is different that the desired - n/m = value - notation. `scanf()` will wait as long as it found the respective characters, which gives chance for messy inputs. Better get the input as whole first and then analyze it. If it wasn't matching or wrong repeat the input operation.

Comment: Yeah like we do arithmetic parsing on the command line prompt, isn't it?